# List all entities resources functionality seems to be failing in API v2

Tags: fiware-orion

If we perform `<cb_url>:<cb_port>/v2/entitites/EntityId/attrs` request as described in http://fiware.github.io/context.Orion/api/v2/cookbook/, we get a "service not found" error.

For this test we used the Docker image from https://hub.docker.com/r/fiware/orion/

Version information about the build:

```
{
  "orion" : {
  "version" : "1.0.0-next",
  "uptime" : "1 d, 3 h, 48 m, 6 s",
  "git_hash" : "b6752828f37711bed6e1ff670207d6b984bc9570",
  "compile_time" : "Tue Apr 5 18:25:46 UTC 2016",
  "compiled_by" : "root",
  "compiled_in" : "838a42ae8431"
  }
}
```

### Steps to replicate:

Create an entity:

```
(curl -X POST <orion_host>:1026/v2/Entities?options=keyValues -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --header 'Accept: application/json' -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
{
    "type": "Review",
    "id": "review-36",
    "author": "AuthorId",
    "itemReviewed": "LeBistro",
    "reviewBody": "Body of the review",
    "ratingValue": 4
}
EOF
```

Try to retrieve its attributes with:

```
curl <orion_host>:1026/v2/Entities/review-36/attrs
```

or

```
curl <orion_host>:1026/v2/Entities/review-36/attrs?options=keyValues
```

In both cases we get:

```
{
    "error": "BadRequest",
    "description": "service not found"
}
```

If we perform:

```
curl <orion_host>:1026/v2/Entities/review-36
```

We get:

```
{
    "id": "review-36",
    "type": "Review",
    "author":
    {
        "type": "none",
        "value": "AuthorId",
        "metadata": {}
    },
    "itemReviewed":
    {
        "type": "none",
        "value": "LeBistro",
        "metadata": {}
    },
    "ratingValue":
    {
        "type": "none",
        "value": 4,
        "metadata": {}
    },
    "reviewBody":
    {
        "type": "none",
        "value": "Body of the review",
        "metadata": {}
    }
}
```

Or if we perform :

```
curl <orion_host>:1026/v2/Entities/review-36?options=keyValues
```

We get:

```
{
    "id": "review-36",
    "type": "Review",
    "author": "AuthorId",
    "itemReviewed": "LeBistro",
    "ratingValue": 4,
    "reviewBody": "Body of the review"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use [reference](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/) instead of [cookbook](http://fiware.github.io/context.Orion/api/v2/cookbook/).

And in this case your problem is that the url `/v2/Entities/review-36/attrs` is malformed.

Possible Requests:

- `GET /v2/entities`  --> return all entities
- `GET /v2/entities/<id>` --> return an entity associated to this id
- `GET /v2/entities/<id>/attrs/<attr_name>` --> return only an attribute in  the entity associated to this id
- `GET /v2/entities/<id>/attrs/<attr_name>/value` --> return only the attribute value associated to an attribute into an entity with this id

Answer (score 0):

I think the /attrs is not a "malformed URL" it is something not already implemented ...

Comment: Not really. See details at https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/2008#issuecomment-206986257